# How to access base class's member variable in c++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to access base class's member variable..
How to do that?

===================== Following is ClassA (parent class) ===========================

```
class ClassA 
{
public:
    int member_Var; // Parent member_var

    ClassA();
    ~ClassA();
    void ClassA::initProcess();
};

ClassA::ClassA(){}
ClassA::~ClassA(){}

void ClassA::initProcess()
{
   member_Var = 20;
}
```

================= Following is ClassB of ClassA's subclass ================

```
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
public:
    int member_Var; // Subclass member_var

    ClassB();
    ~ClassB();

    void ClassB::initProcess();
};

ClassB::ClassB(){}
ClassB::~ClassB(){}

void ClassB::initProcess()
{
   ClassA->member_Var = 10; // Is this correct? or How to access base instances's member variable?
   member_var = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify `ClassA::member_Var` to explicitly refer to the one in base class.

```
void ClassB::initProcess()
{
   ClassA::member_Var = 10;
   member_var = 100;
}
```